# How to store user input to a json file?

Tags: python, json

I am working on a project called password manager,for that i need to store the passwords and emails and i need to access password whenever user type a corresponding email i am trying to store them in a json file ,but iam unable to store user input to a json file

```
if choice=="A":
    Email = input("Enter your email..")
    password = input("Enter your password..")

    manager = """{
        "email":Email
        "password":"password"
    }"""
```

This is the code that i have written

Comment: If you store the email and password in a dict, then it should be very easy to output to a json file using the json module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module

```
import json

if choice == "A":
    email = input("Enter your email: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")

    manager = {
        "email": email,
        "password": password
    }

    with open("file.json", "w") as file:
         json.dump(manager, file)
```